# Unexpected behavior in a nested while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to better understand how Python flow control works.  Accordingly, I wrote a little script to understand how to make functional menus that include the ability to enter and leave sub-menus.  The code below works as expected (no errors, it prints the expected output, etc). But when I enter option 4 "Exit" in the sub-menu "stage1" it accepts the input and re-prints the sub-menu.  If I select option 4 again it exits the sub-menu and returns me to the main menu.

Why would it work after selecting the option twice?

I trimmed my code down to include the snippet for your review, and once I trimmed it down, it no longer requires I enter the "Exit" option twice.  I'd like to have a menu with more than 1 option, so I'd love to get to the bottom of this.

```
import time
import os

def stage1():
    print("stage1")
    time.sleep(1)
    stage1_loop = 1
    while stage1_loop == 1:
        os.system('clear')
        print("Sub Menu")
        print("1. Stage 1")
        print("4. Exit")
        option = int(input("Please select a stage."))
        if option == 1:
            stage1()
        elif option == 2:
            stage2()
        elif option == 3:
            stage3()
        elif option == 4:
            print("Exit")
            stage1_loop = 0

main_loop = 1
while main_loop == 1:
    os.system('clear')
    print("Main Menu")
    print("1. Stage 1")
    print("4. Exit")
    option = int(input("Please select a stage."))
    if option == 1:
        stage1()
    elif option == 2:
        stage2()
    elif option == 3:
        stage3()
    elif option == 4:
        print("Exit")
        main_loop = 0

##############################################################
        print("Main Menu")
        for stage in [1, 2, 3]: 
            print(f"{stage}. Stage {stage}")
        print("4. Exit")
```

If I comment out the elif lines for stage 2 & 3 in the sub-menu then the issue disappears.

EDIT - after removing the recursive call to stage 1 I fixed my issue (see answers below.  Pasted in the code snippet suggested by one of the answers to clean up my menu printing code.  Cheers!

Comment: Try printing different things in the function and it of it. Then you will understand better which code is running

Comment: The behavior you are describing would take place only if after entering stage 1, the operator would choose again stage1 - as the function is entered twice, nested, it also has to be exited twice via the 4th option.

Comment: if run this same code, and immediately after entering stage 1, you pick 4, it will exit everything as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite messy:

- You don't require to create variables for while. You can use `True` and `break`
- Looks like you're repeating code a lot of times, we'll fix that later on

Here's the fixed code:

```
import time
import os

def stage1():
    print("stage1")
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        # os.system('clear')
        print("Sub Menu")
        print("1. Stage 1")
        print("4. Exit")
        option = int(input("Please select a stage."))
        if option == 1:
            stage1()
        elif option == 2:
            stage2()
        elif option == 3:
            stage3()
        elif option == 4:
            print("Exit")
            return True # returns true and exits the loop

while True:
    # os.system('clear')
    print("Main Menu")
    print("1. Stage 1")
    print("4. Exit")
    option = int(input("Please select a stage."))
    if option == 1:
        if stage1(): # checks if stage 4 is True and then breaks the loop
            break
    elif option == 2:
        stage2()
    elif option == 3:
        stage3()
    elif option == 4:
        print("Exit")
        break
```

Here's a faster non-repeating code for all `4 stages`:

```
import time
import os

def stageFunction(stage):
    if stage in [1,2,3]: print(f"Stage {stage}") # Fast print stage number
    if stage == 1:
        # Do whatever
        pass
    elif stage == 2:
        # DO whatever
        pass
    elif stage == 3:
        # Do whatever
        pass
    elif stage == 4:
        print("Exit")
        # Do whatever
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Stage!")

def stageSystem(stage=0):
    # os.system('clear')
    print("Main Menu")
    for i in range(1,4):
        print(f"{i}. Stage {i}") # fast print stages
    print("4. Exit")
    option = stage
    if (not stage): 
        option = int(input("Please select a stage: "))
        stageSystem(option)
    else:
        stageFunction(stage)
        stageSystem() # recursive call
stageSystem()
```

*It might look lengthy, but it works pretty well considering you have 4 stages.*

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The root issue was the recursive call to stage1, but you're right that my code is bulky and not as clean as possible.  I'm pretty new to all this.  That being said I implemented your suggestion for the print function and it worked like a charm.  Although I'm pretty sure you meant to put in a "for" loop instead of an "if".  I'll paste the updated code in my question if you're curious what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple potential issues here, let's get into it:

- First issue: `stage1` is recursive:

You've included a call to stage 1 inside stage 1.
Which means that when you call the `stage1` function if you press `1`, you have created a sub-sub menu.

To fix this issue is suggest the following edit:

```py
def stage1():
    print("stage1")
    time.sleep(1)
    stage1_loop = 1
    while stage1_loop == 1:
        os.system('clear')
        print("Sub Menu")
        print("1. Stage 1")
        print("4. Exit")
        option = int(input("Please select a stage."))
        if option == 1:
            continue  # This skips to the next loop iteration
        elif option == 2:
            stage2()
        elif option == 3:
            stage3()
        elif option == 4:
            print("Exit")
            stage1_loop = 0
```

- Second issue: You'd like for exit to quit, but you are inside a sub menu.

For that simply call the `exit()` method and your code will terminate altogether. You won't need to exit the submenu and then the menu.

Note: I may have misunderstood this last point, in that case simply ignore the second issue.

Comment: This is what I get for trying to write code in the middle of the night.  You nailed it on the recursive issue.  I was testing the function in the sub menu for option 1, which put me in a sub-sub-menu, so when I exited I just went back to the sub menu.  I removed the recursive labeling and function call and it works perfectly.